# Angular with angularfire2 - getDownloadURL() won't work sometimes. Is this because of async

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-storage, angularfire2

GET https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/xxxxx/o/hw04.docx 404
firebase download link err t {code_: "storage/object-not-found", message_: "Firebase Storage: Object 'hw04.docx' does not exist.", serverResponse_: "{↵  "error": {↵    "code": 404,↵    "message": "No…not get object",↵    "status": "GET_OBJECT"↵  }↵}", name_: "FirebaseError"}

Here is my code snippet for the same.

```js
upload(event) {
    const file = event.target.files[0];
    this.randomId = file.name;
    this.ref = this.afStorage.ref(this.randomId);
      this.task = this.ref.put(file);
      this.uploadProgress = this.task.percentageChanges();
      console.log("before pipe",this.task);
      this.ref.getDownloadURL().subscribe((url) => {
          console.log("link", url)
          this.downloadURL = url;
        },
        err => {
            console.log("firebase download link err", err);
        })
    }
}
```

It works fine like 60% of the time otherwise it'll give **404 download link err**.

Is there any better way to handle this async response?

Please help me!

Thanks,

Comment: You have a race condition.  You should wait until the upload is fully complete before getting the download URL.

Comment: You're right. Thanks @DougStevenson

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/1649#issuecomment-389207417

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `finalize` method from rxjs:

```
task.snapshotChanges().pipe(
    finalize(() => this.downloadURL = fileRef.getDownloadURL() )
 )
.subscribe()
```

It will set the download url when the upload is complete.

Comment: Yes, I tried something like this and it worked. Thanks for your response @beniamin